Is RosJava still supported?
I see that there are no questions about rosjava since 2019.  Either the code and documentation is perfect (a dream) or there is no support still available.  Is there any play to support ros in java?  Can it be done? Is there any guidance (other than convert to C++/python)?

Seems to be dead, the repo was archived last year.
